# LibreOffice Impress: Distorted image in presentation mode

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, libreoffice-impress, openoffice-impress

When using the `SlideShow` option in LibreOffice Impress, some images that were totally fine on the document appear distorted on the slide show (see example below). The problem doesn't happen when exporting in pdf, nor does it happen when the presentation is shrank to just one slide... (making it difficult to present a minimal reproducible example, but here is the [slide example](https://It%20doesn%27t%20happen%20when%20exporting%20in%20pdf,%20nor%20does%20it%20happen%20when%20the%20presentation%20is%20shrank%20to%20just%20one%20slide...%20so%20difficult%20to%20present%20a%20minimal%20reproducible%20example)).

This problem has been asked on the [LibreOffice forum](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/distorted-images-and-page-numbers-when-presenting/30214) and on [another page](https://makandracards.com/makandra/9395-libreoffice-impress-distorted-text-letters-in-presentation-mode) but no convincing answers were given.

What could trigger this distortion? A memory/size issue noting that the problem doesn't happen if the presentation has only one slide?

Thanks!

##### The slide in libroffice normal mode

[image]

##### The slide in libroffice slideshow

[image]

Comment: Since it distorted only the *last* image, have you tried adding a fourth, perhaps just a few pixels or all transparent?